# Sharing a local storage object across a web-app and a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I need to store a users profile and his preferences in a localStorage object \ cookies in a way that they'll be accessible(readable) and writable from both the web-app, and the chrome extension (that are basically part of the same product).

I found [this cool library](https://github.com/CypherX/xAuth) and [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/) that specifies how to use it.

The problem is that xauth.org is down, and so is the [server page](http://xauth.org/server.html) that is required to use the library.

Any alternatives

Comment: Err. Context scripts share access to domain's `localStorage`.

Comment: the domain is chrome-extension://{id} thus not accessible from the web, or am I missing something?

Comment: Note: [*content* scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). If you inject a script into the page in question, `localStorage` will be shared.

Comment: So, basically you are suggesting to add the web-app's domain to the list of matching domains, and then the chrome.localStorage object will be available from the web, even on non-chrome browsers?, doesn't sound rational

Comment: What's `chrome.localStorage`? Are you confusing things with `chrome.storage.local`?

Comment: Yup, I am using `chrome.storage.sync.set` and `chrome.storage.sync.get`.
Does it make things more tricky?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57012/discussion-between-oleg-tikhonov-and-xan).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use both `localStorage` and cookies.

1. If you inject a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in the web app's page, its `localStorage` is shared with domain's own storage. You can then [communicate](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) with your background script to pass information.
2. If you include `"cookies"` permission in your manifest, you can [manipulate cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) using `chrome.cookies` API.

Edit: You can also make your extension [externally connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) from the web app to maintain synchronization of the changes.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2016

This [cross-storage](https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage) from zendesk is a great alternative to the 2 librarys that you mention

Even better you can config which client site/domain has a specific permission (either to get, set, delete)

Sample codes:

```
Hub

// Config s.t. subdomains can get, but only the root domain can set and del
CrossStorageHub.init([
  {origin: /\.example.com$/,            allow: ['get']},
  {origin: /:\/\/(www\.)?example.com$/, allow: ['get', 'set', 'del']}
]);
```

Note the $ for matching the end of the string. The RegExps in the above example will match origins such as valid.example.com, but not invalid.example.com.malicious.com.

```
Client

var storage = new CrossStorageClient('https://store.example.com/hub.html');

storage.onConnect().then(function() {
  return storage.set('newKey', 'foobar');
}).then(function() {
  return storage.get('existingKey', 'newKey');
}).then(function(res) {
  console.log(res.length); // 2
}).catch(function(err) {
  // Handle error
});
```